# How can I print the node title in Time Spent view?

Tags: 8, views

I'm trying to create a (page)view with time spent on different nodes filtered by logged in user. To do this I use the [Time Spent](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_spent) module. When trying to create a Time Spent view, the only thing I can output is the `time spent id` and the `time spent length`. I am also able to get the `user` as a relationship. With this I can create the contextual filter to filter on user.

But now I still have a list of random ID's with a time next to it. Without knowing on what node the time is spent.

So my solution was to add a new relationship to this view type to fetch the connected nodes field values. But I don't really understand what I'm doing. By copy and pasting in `time_spent_views.inc` I created the following relationship:

```
  $data['time_spent_page']['nid'] = array(
    'title' => t('Node'),
    'help' => t('Node time spent.'),
    'relationship' => array(
      'base' => 'node',
      'base field' => 'nid',
      'id' => 'standard',
      'label' => t('Node time spent'),
    ),
  );
```

This does give me more fields to display, but not the fields I want. I get fields like `Link to content`, `Link to edit content`. But no `ID` or `Title` field. How to expand this to also see the field of a node like, title and other fields?

Comment: I'm wondering that this is not built-in yet into the named module, surely would make sense as a feature request then. Have you already asked the maintainers?

Comment: No it is not currently built-in. I added a feature request to the modules page. But if I know how to fix it I can even provide them with a patch to solve it quickly. So all help is still welcome.